# Which SMTP code must the server return when the Email could not be delivered to all recipients?

Tags: email, smtp, rfc

Which SMTP code must the server return when the Email could not be delivered to all recipients?

I mean the case when there are multiple recipient.

Let's say there are RCPT A, RCPT B, RCPT C and the end of the DATA the server can deliver to A and B, but not to C.

As a server, I must not response with code 250. Right? Then which code must I response with?

And the other hand, I neither can give them code 5xx, because they may double the Email for A and B.

Answer (score 0):

In typical implementation/scenario:

- server refuses to accept "obviously" invalid recipients in reply to `RCPT TO:`
  (e.g. non existing DNS domain or non existing user/mailbox in local email domain)
- accepts message in reply to the final dot (or rejects it as spam)
- tries to send accepted message to recipients
- sends back "bounce messages" to envelope sender (`MAIL FROM:`) **after** repeated/multiple delivery attempts fail

Comment: [quote]sends back "bounce messages" to envelope sender (MAIL FROM:) after repeated/multiple delivery attempts fail[/quote]
what if permanent delivery error (for certain recipient) is known right after the final dot? accept and send bounce message immediately?

Comment: AFAIK most implementation does not handle this special case differently.  They follow "queue and acknowledge the final dot".  "Try first delivery attempt and acknowledge" approach is more complicated to implement (more special cases e.g. **LONG** initial delivery time). See sendmail's double interactive delivery mode for different approach - https://serverfault.com/a/490185/163277